# Qt Error: C:\Users\user-pc\Proj1\main.cpp:6: error: variable 'QApplication prog' has initializer but incomplete type QApplication prog(argc, argv);

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtgui, qmainwindow

I'm new in Qt programming and followed this [tutorial](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=57&number=4).

In this tutorial there is a complicated program on earth and it goes like that:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication prog(argc, argv);
    QLabel *l = new QLabel("Itay's First GUI in C++!!");
    l->show();
    return prog.exec();
}
```

for some reason I get these  errors:

```
C:\Users\user-pc\Tutorial\main.cpp:6: error: variable 'QApplication prog' has initializer but incomplete type
 QApplication prog(argc, argv);
                   ^
C:\Users\user-pc\Tutorial\main.cpp:10: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Can somebody tell me this reason for this ?

Comment: Didn't you include `<QApplication>` ?

Comment: Try to `#include <QApplication>` on the top of the file.

Answer (score 9):

You need to include the `QApplication` header:

```
#include <QApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "has initializer but incomplete type" means that the class is forward declared, and not defined.

As already mentioned, `#include <QApplication>` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm new in Qt programming and followed the tutorial http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=57&number=4 in this tutorial there is the most complicated program on earth and it goes like that:

You have not mentioned to carefully listen to the video. Let us see the relevant screenshot from the video:

[image]

As you can see they do include this line:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

Your code is missing that and that is why it does not compile because when you are trying to use this statement:

```
QApplication prog(argc, argv);
```

It will not find the definition of the `QApplication` class.

You have another problem though. You also include "mainwindow.h", whereas you do not really have a MainWindow instance. Having these two main issues fixed, your working code should be something like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication prog(argc, argv);
    QLabel *l = new QLabel("Itay's First GUI in C++!!");
    l->show();
    return prog.exec();
}
```

Please note that I used

```
#include <QApplication>
```

as opposed to

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

because the former will work with Qt 5, too. The QApplication class, along with several other classes, was put into the `QtWidgets` module. Also, this is more consistent with the `QLabel` inclusion.